# R - mutate getting the first smaller value from the top rows

Tags: r, mutate

So, the problem is, I'm trying to get the first smaller value within the top rows of the transformed variable.
My df looks something like:

| count |
| --- |
| 24 |
| 33 |
| 33 |
| 34 |
| 35 |
| 33 |
| 34 |
| 35 |
| ... |

It only contains a column. The output that I'm looking for:

| count | close_prev |
| --- | --- |
| 24 | NA |
| 33 | 24 |
| 33 | 24 |
| 34 | 33 |
| 35 | 34 |
| 33 | 24 |
| 33 | 24 |
| 34 | 33 |
| 35 | 34 |

So, I'm looking for the first smaller number from the top rows.

The code I have so far:

```
table %>%
   mutate(close_prev = map_dbl(row_number(), ~closest(count[seq_len(max(.x - 1, 1))], count[.x])))
```

It's not working :c
Can someone help me?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can `match()` the value against itself and then index the result against `count` padded with an `NA`.

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  mutate(x = c(NA, count)[match(count, count)])

# A tibble: 9 × 2
  count close_prev
  <dbl>      <dbl>
1    24         NA
2    33         24
3    33         24
4    34         33
5    35         34
6    33         24
7    33         24
8    34         33
9    35         34
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a rolling join. This is available in `dplyr 1.1.0` and above:

```r
left_join(a, a, join_by(closest(count > count)), multiple = "first")

  count.x count.y
1      24      NA
2      33      24
3      33      24
4      34      33
5      35      34
6      33      24
7      33      24
8      34      33
9      35      34
```

---

In `data.table`, you can use `roll = "nearest"`:

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(a)
a[a, on = "count", roll = "nearest", mult = "first"][]
```